# Why is there no deduction guide for string_view?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, template-meta-programming, string-view

When looking at the reference of [`basic_string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view), there seems to be a lack of (explicit) deduction guide for constructing from `std::basic_string` - coincident or not, it seems that implicit deduction guides are generated for the pointer types (`const char*` and `const wchar_t*`)

Currently Im resorting to the following **trick** in a template that should just accept anything that can be stuck onto a *string view*:

```
using CharIn = decltype(std::basic_string(str_in))::value_type;//basicly: char or wchar_t

std::basic_string_view<CharIn> str = str_in;
```

I would have prefered to just write:

```
std::basic_string_view str = str_in;//<--using deduction guide (currently does not work for basic_string)
```

Im wondering wrether this has been considered ?

Comment: It's probably relative safety: an rvalue `basic_string`s binds to `const basic_string &` and creates a dangling view. A (raw) string literal doesn't dangle.

Comment: @Caleth If I understand your argument correctly, it doesn't hold up: https://foonathan.net/2017/03/string_view-temporary/

Comment: @rustyx Yes, you can construct a `string_view` from `string` without further ado. Just the deduction guides seem to be missing for the templated case I guess?

Comment: The problem here is similar to that of `template <CharT> void foo(std::basic_string_view<CharT>)`, `CharT` doesn't get deduced

Comment: @Caleth Good point. Here's a source that mentions that problem: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/stdstring_view-the-duct-tape-of-string-types/

Comment: "coincidently it seems that implicit deduction guides are generated.." -- there's no coincidence about that.

Comment: What is `str_in`? Is it a `std::string` or `char const*` or what?

Comment: @Duane - I was trying to be cute; and didn't make my point clearly. There are no explicit deduction guides for `basic_string_view` because the implicitly generated ones were deemed sufficient. _That_ was an explicit decision, not a coincidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double implicit conversions of the sort you're trying are, generally speaking, a really bad idea, and the C++ standard does whatever it can to stop you from trying to do them. Overload resolution doesn't allow it, for example; if a conversion sequence would try to do a double-conversion, it just stops considering that overload altogether.

Let's consider the intent of your deduction guide: to allow `std::basic_string_view str = str_in;` to work for any type `T` which is implicitly convertible, not to a `basic_string_view` of some kind, but to a `basic_string`.

OK, so... what does `std::basic_string_view str = str_in;` actually do? Well, it has to convert whatever `str_in` is to a `basic_string` of some sort. So either `str_in` is a type which can call a single-argument constructor of `basic_string` or `str_in` is a type with an overloaded `operator basic_string<...>`.

Let's consider the single-argument constructors of `basic_string`. These include: an allocator-only one for making an empty string, a copy constructor, a move constructor, an initializer-list constructor, and one that takes a `const charT*`. Only the latter one would be useful for this case, so `str_in` would have to be some `charT*` type. Well, `basic_string_view`'s *implicit* deduction guides can already handle this just fine. So there is no need for double-conversion.

So we're now only talking about the case where `str_in` is a type that has a conversion operator. OK: does this conversion operator return a *reference* to a `basic_string` type?

Because if it doesn't, then `std::basic_string_view str = str_in;` will yield a dangling reference. A temporary `basic_string` will be created, and its contents will be referenced by the view. Then the temporary gets destroyed, and our view instantly becomes worthless.

Things like this are why C++ doesn't like double implicit conversions. If you had to type this: `std::basic_string_view str = basic_string(str_in);`, then it would be clear to everyone why your code is broken: you're storing a view of a temporary.

If `str_in` is a string type itself, then it would be better to just give it an `operator basic_string_view` overload.

Comment: Are you arguiing that a deduction guide is a type of conversion ? because you can already assign a std::string to a std::string_view, ie. with explicit template parameters, so it's just the deduction thats not happening.

Comment: @darune: I'm arguing that the only way to *use* that deduction guide is to go through the motions of calling a constructor that requires a double conversion. So there's really no difference. `std::string` converts to a `string_view` because of a conversion operator in `string`, not a constructor in `string_view`. That is, it is the string type's responsibility to provide conversion to the view, not the other way around.

Comment: Hmm, I see, that actually surprised me a bit - why did they choose that design over the other is a bit puzzling though. Usually, conversion operators are best used for the very simplest cases (when other options are not possible even) and does not 'scale' very well design-wise.

Comment: @darune: `string_view` is supposed to be a lingua franca type. You put `string_view` in your interface, and that interface now supports any string type which is convertible to `string_view`. Since `string_view` is a standard-defined type, the only way for a user-defined string type to be convertible to `string_view` is for each string type to provide a conversion operator to `string_view`. So that means each string type is supposed to "speak" `string_view`; it's not `string_view` that changes for each string type.